# How does using a variable for file paths work?

Tags: c++

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("C:/FilePathThatWorks");
```

The above seems to work in C++. But if I try and take a String, or CString, or anything else, and plug it in for `inFile.open(ExampleString)`, it fails at compile time (error at the bottom of this question). The question is not about my code, but how to make C++ accept a variable for `inFile`.

If it only ever accepts char* variables, then is there perhaps a method that takes input from the user in the form of a char* with the null terminator and everything.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&)'
```

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using? If you check the reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/ you'll see that C++98 only supports ```const char*``` while C++11 supports ```const string&.```

Comment: ExampleString.c_str() may be what you are looking for

Comment: The error seems to suggest that the compiler supports C++ 11 because the string seems to be C++ 11, but that contradicts the fact that the file stream doesn't. Even though you seem to have solved your immediate problem, the behaviour is still unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `open` in `fstream` does not accept `std::string`. You need to pass a `char*`.

So just call `c_str()` on `string`.

Comment: [This is only true before C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open). std::strings are perfectly acceptable for a long time now.

Comment: Huh. I wonder why so many tutorials used different libraries for CString when it's inbuilt to String. Thank you immensely. This works.

Comment: `CString` is the name of a class from MCF. I don't know what `String` might refer to. If you elaborated a bit on that, you could improve your chance at getting answers.

Answer (score 2):

ifstream requires a char* param for the filename. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

most string classes have some way to convert to this kind of string (e.g. c_str())

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use CString:

```
CString path = "c:\\FilePathThatWorks";

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(static_cast<const char*>(path));
```

The cast is not needed here.

`CString` can represent two different strings depending on the project settings. If it is a string of `char` the code should compile, if the character type is `wchar_t` compiling should fail.